# Rainloop: arbitrary sender address?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I just set up my mailserver (Postfix as SMTP and Dovecot for IMAP) and as web frontend I use Rainloop - which also works very well! My setup is that I have only very few real users (actualy at the moment it's just me ;-) ) but I configured a catch-all to forward all mails to my account. When I now receive a mail at stackoverflow@mydomain.com and I want to reply to that, I want the sender to be stackoverflow@mydomain.com. At the moment Rainloop would use my@mydomain.com (which is also the user name I used to log in). Is there a way that I can arbitratyly set the sender address? (I mean of course only the part before the @.)

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the [demo](http://demo.rainloop.net/) for about five seconds, I found the menu point "Settings -> Identities". Add another identity with the required mail address and select it for sending.

Comment: How could I have missed that! Thanks, that's the solution!

Comment: This requires to set up identities for every local mail address, which is for big number (or even a catchall) a nightmare.

Comment: @sebix: A very common case is that you might have a lot of receiving addresses, but just a small number of addresses you actual sent mails from, making this identity approach feasible.